# CART selection and *deselection* classification tree

Tags: r, classification, cart

I came across a line in Peterson, et al. (2016) that says:

> The specific settings applied in the `rpart` procedure ensured that only the largest subgroup would be further split in order to create a deselection rather than a selection algorithm.
>   (from the section headed, "Methods used for developing the KIDScore algorithm")

I think that I'm quite familiar with the implementation of CART but I don't have any idea what the authors of the article mean.

Does someone have an idea what they mean? Which parameter setting might they have used?

---

Bjørn Molt Petersen, Mikkel Boel, Markus Montag, and David K. Gardner;  Development of a generally applicable morphokinetic algorithm capable of predicting the implantation potential of embryos transferred on Day 3, *Human Reproduction*, 2016 (Oxford, England). ([Pubmed abstract](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27609980), [Full article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5027927/))

Comment: Please edit. Include the article's title and authors (and a hyperlink). Please consider contacting the authors and posting their reply. – *Reviewer*

Comment: thanks, Jim, I edit the post, hope it will be useful. I'm trying to look in the literature before I'll contact the authors.

Comment: You're not the first to find that the method sections in medical journals are often... (a bit)... unsatisfactory. :-)

Comment: thank you @jim at least I don't feel alone with it. after researching pretty much, I think the authors meant to set the minimum observation in a leaf in a way it will prevent too much splitting. that's the only reasonable solution I can see.

Comment: Anyway, the line "*[...] to create a deselection rather than a selection algorithm*" does not say very much. Node splitting on a categorical variable (in R: a `factor`) always means: an observation that does not go left ("selected") must go right ("not selected"). (Think: $A \cup A^c = \Omega$).

Comment: My advice would be to contact the authors and link this question. Perhaps they'll provide an answer on this beautiful site. If they provide an answer through mail, please post it here as an [answer to your own question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).